# How to use windows scheduler to execute R script

Tags: r, schedule

I have found some way to solve it
e.g: windows system's task scheduler and R package called taskscheduleR

I only can execute a simple R script , like
    cat(aa,file="ttt.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE) 
but I can't execute the program I really want to execute

the picture is the situation

[image]

I want to know:

if this R script needs other ***.r

what should I key on the command line?

or just put them into the same folder?

now the situation is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the error message, the script is trying to install a package, and you don't have any selected cran mirror in your .Rprofile. Then, it fails as you should manually select a mirror interactively. Either fix this by selecting a mirror, or remove/comment the line in your script that is installing a package from cran and it should works fine.